# H+ vs HCl in the gastric juice

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution

Parietal cells in the stomach are known to expel $\ce{H+}$ ions into the gastric juice to keep the pH acidic. When $\ce{H+}$ $\ce{[H3O+]}$ can fully function as acid in the gastric juice, why do cells combine $\ce{Cl-}$ to form $\ce{HCl}$ in the stomach?

Comment: You can't expel ions of one sign only.

Comment: Well, Parietal cells use ATP to expel H+ generated from H2CO3 and chloride ions are transported into the gastric juice separately via an independent process. So in the juice they become HCl. The question is, why HCl is made when pumping H+ itself should be good enough to keep the stomach liquid acidic?

Comment: It is not an independent process. You can't just pump H+ and leave it at that. Or rather, you can, but this would have certain unintended consequences, like some negative ions creeping seemingly out of nowhere.

Comment: If you only pump ions of one charge, e.g. positive, into a system, you will find that there is attraction of those ions to negative ions elsewhere. Thus, the $\ce{H+}$ will "drag the $\ce{Cl-}$ ions along". Note that in the gastric fluid itself, I expect that the two kinds of ions will be fully dissociated due to the strength of hydrochloric acid and a sufficient concentration of water being present.